# Android Progress Dialog Issue

Tags: android, progressdialog

I've been trying to get ProgressDialog to work.

At first, I had it inside activity, but it was not showing up no matter how many permutations and combinations I tried.

Then I moved it inside AsyncTask. I'm initializing and showing it in onPreExecute, and dismissing it in onPostExecute.

```
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute(){
    try {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context,
                ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error);
        dialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TASK_TAG, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure what should be used as context. When I try activity.getApplicationContext, following exception is thrown android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application.

When tried with activity, the dialog is not shown.

When I enclose the dialog.show in try / catch, it doesn't show. When it is not enclosed, it seems the Exception takes down the App.

I have a few questions -

1. What is the recommended way of showing Progress Dialog? Is it through Async Task?
2. If yes, what should be used as Context?
3. If it is one of the two choices mentioned, why is the App throwing these Exceptions?

Comment: show your code.  You should use the context of the current active Activity

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the progressDialog inside your AsyncTask, so AsyncTask and Activity are not linked, it's possible that the activity dies and the asynctask continues his execution.

```
new YourAsyncTask(context).execute(...);
```

You have to create a custom contructor for your Asynctask:

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     private Context context;
     private Dialog dialog;

     public YourAsyncTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute(){
        try {
           dialog = new ProgressDialog(context,
                ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
           dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
           dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
           dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error);
           dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TASK_TAG, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
     }

     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         ...
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
             dialog.dismiss();
         }
         ....
     }
 }
```

Comment: This would be the way to do it, pass in the context. Use publishProgress() to update the progress bar incrementally. AsyncTask has a method called onProgressUpdate() that you can call each iteration for example or each time a progress is done during doInBackground().

Answer (score 0):

> 1.What is the recommended way of showing Progress Dialog? Is it through Async Task?

-- Depends upon your requirement. But if you have a situation where you want to do some operation in your `AsyncTask` and you don't want the user to interact with your app during that time, you can show the Dialog in `onPreExecute()` of `AsyncTask`.

> 2. If yes, what should be used as Context?

-- The context should be the activity context everytime you use `ProgressDialog` so as to avoid the exception.

> 3. If it is one of the two choices mentioned, why is the App throwing these Exceptions?

-- Exception is because the context is invalid. You should use Activity context;